# Snapshot of Ubuntu 22.04 that I can restore in case of failure

Tags: 22.04, backup

I guess Ubuntu has no Reset option. Luckily, everything is fine on my Ubuntu 22.04. Wondering whether it is possible to create a snapshot of my Ubuntu which I can restore back to in case something goes wrong. Is it possible to keep it on external storage?

My Ubuntu partition is 160 GB. Thanks.

Comment: You've not said which Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product you're using.. Desktop? Server? etc

Comment: Read `man -k backup` to get a list of `man` pages to read. Reboot into single user mode to minimize the number of open, changing files. Yes, it's possible/easy to use an external disk. Read `man mount fstab blkid`. Beware didks poisoned by Windows "Fast Boot" setting. They look like junk to Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc HP laptop. Regret the confusion. Hi waltinator , thanks. I ended up using TimeShift.

Answer (score 0):

I found Timeshift that works for me.

https://github.com/linuxmint/timeshift

Perhaps there are better options. For now, Timeshft takes a backup of Ubuntu 22.04 for me that I can restore when something goes wrong. I can even use an external device to store them.